# Как на лету сгенерировать наследник интерфейса на Kotlin?

Tags: рефлексия, kotlin, runtime

Существует некий интерфейс, предположим, имеющий вид

```
interface Example {
    fun one()
    fun two()
}
```

Мне необходимо во время исполнения кода создать реализацию этого интерфейса. Возможно ли это? Если возможно - как? Я так и не смог найти ни документацию, ни какие-то советы по этой теме.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На данный момент нет возможности создавать классы на лету (как это делается через Java Compiler для Java классов). По этой причине пока что предпочтительно использовать компиляцию на лету для Java классов (благо, Kotlin и Java вроде как обратно совместимы)